# yii select outputs only first column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, yii

I have this php code:

```
$categories = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('dt_add, name, domain, category, promo_type, hash, link')
    ->from('webmaster_links')
    ->where('webmaster_id = ' . Yii::app()->user->id)
    ->queryColumn();
var_dump($categories);
```

It should echo array with all values but it echoing only values of `dt_add`.

Output:

```
array(7) { [0]=> string(26) "2022-06-17 15:27:35.000000" [1]=> string(26) "2022-06-17 15:39:45.000000" [2]=> string(26) "2022-06-17 15:44:38.000000" [3]=> string(26) "2022-06-17 15:44:38.000000" [4]=> string(26) "2022-06-17 15:49:35.000000" [5]=> string(26) "2022-06-17 15:57:44.000000" [6]=> string(26) "2022-06-17 15:58:28.000000" }
```

What's wrong? I copied code from [www.yiiframework.com](http://www.yiiframework.com) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've got it. It should be queryAll, not queryColumn.
Final Code:

```
$categories = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('dt_add, name, domain, category, promo_type, hash, link')
    ->from('webmaster_links')
    ->where('webmaster_id = ' . Yii::app()->user->id)
    ->queryAll();
var_dump($categories);
```